# Action Bar (Toolbar) Icon

Tags: android

I have navigation drawer, in order to show it over Action bar, I made custom Toolbar View and set it as Action Bar. And now I have arrow icon which I can't change.

This is part of my **Base Activity**, I tried those methods, nothing changes:

```
protected void onCreateDrawer()
    {

        // R.id.drawer_layout should be in every activity with exactly the same id.
        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle((Activity) this, drawerLayout, R.drawable.ic_drawer, 0, 0)
        {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view)
            {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.app_name);
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView)
            {

               getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Aaaaaaaaaaa");
            }
        };
        drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(drawerToggle);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.ic_drawer);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
```

part of XML of **MainActivity** where I have Toolbar, and all content of Activity set in frame layout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false">
    <!-- The main content view -->


    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize">
```

Navigation Drawer over Action bar works great, but, I can not change any of icon on Toolbar.

I set icon on toolbar before adding it like Action Bar and it works great, but no way that I can set title or something else with ActionBar/Toolbar.

Screenshot:  [image: Screenshot]

Comment: clarify your problem

Comment: add these lines `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);`

Comment: I have already those lines... See code. 

My problem is that i can not set anything on actionbar/toolbar. Title etc...

Comment: Please post a screenshot to let people see what's going on.

Comment: @HiI'mFrogatto, see edit, posted SS.

Comment: I don't see nothing criminal here, but xml - toolbar is your content layout, srsly?

Comment: @ViktorYakunin Noo... My toolbar is in content. I can include it or something. 

I can't find any solution other than this to hide actionbar when drawer is open...

Comment: @Sasaman include toolbar and frameLayout into LinearLayout. In your drawer layout there should be 2 views - contentView and drawerView

Comment: @Sasaman one more thing, you should set title like this 'setTitle("AAAA")' inside your activity, in the fragment - getActivity().setTitle("AAAA");

Answer (score 0):

Use `toolbar.setTitle("Aaaaaaaaa")` instead of

```
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Aaaaaaaa");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/custom_actionbar"
    style="@style/ToolBarStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/transparent"
    android:minHeight="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

In **Base Activity** set your title to textview

```
 Toolbar mToolbar =(Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.metro_toolbar_actionbar);
TextView mTitle = (TextView) mToolbar.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
mTitle.setText("Your text");
```